# How do I use Kombu within Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery, kombu

What is the right way to use Kombu within Django? Here's my working code, which is in `app_name/tasks.py`:

```
import json

from kombu import Connection, Producer, Exchange
from django.conf import settings
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def update_metadata(message, *args, **kwargs):
    print(message)
    message_dict = json.loads(message)
    # process the message
    # convert it into consumable format?
    # update the local file
    publish_metadata(message_dict)


def publish_metadata(message):
    """Puts the metadata in the outbound queues
    """
    connection = Connection(settings.BROKER_URL)
    connection.connect()
    exchange = Exchange(name=settings.OUTBOUND_EXCHANGE, type='fanout')
    producer = Producer(channel=connection, serializer='json',
                        exchange=exchange)
    producer.publish(body=message, serializer='json')
```

But every time it wants to publish a message, it makes a new connection to the exchange. Also, I want to use Kombu, not Celery in `publish_metadata`. I want to push a message to queue and consumer is not Celery. So I cannot use Celery because Celery adds lots of parameters and stuff to the body.

Comment: did you found an answer?